# include js file in blade templating

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7, scaffolding

I am coding an app using laravel and blade template engine and. I am including my page specific scripts in a section called page-scripts that gets yielded in the main layout where the main script is placed but that doesn't work and I keep getting "cannot read property x of null" which means the dom elements are not visible by the script.

This is the main layout

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <!-- CSRF Token -->
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

 <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

 <!-- Scripts -->
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
 @yield('page-scripts')

 <!-- Fonts -->
 <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;0,800;0,900;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Styles -->
 <link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">

     @auth
         <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-red-500 p-6 font-nunito">
             <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
                 <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Innova</span>
             </div>
             <div class="block lg:hidden">
                 <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-white border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
                     <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
                 </button>
             </div>
             <div class="w-full block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
                 <div class="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
                     <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-4">
                         Lista canali
                     </a>
                     <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-4">
                         Generale
                     </a>
                     <a href="#responsive-header" class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white">
                         Profilo
                     </a>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                     <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-red-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0">Logout</a>
                     <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                         @csrf
                     </form>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </nav>
     @endauth

     <main class="py-4">
         @yield('content')
     </main>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here I have one of my pages

```
@section('page-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/page.js') }}"></script>

@endsection

@section('content')
    <form class="w-full max-w-lg" action="{{'/post/'.Request::path()}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 font-nunito">
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                <label class="block tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
                    Condividi qualcosa con gli altri innovatori
                </label>
                <input  class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" name="title" placeholder="Titolo"/>
                @error('title')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">Il post deve avere un titolo</p>
                @enderror
                <textarea  class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" name="body" placeholder="Testo"></textarea>
                @error('body')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">Niente post muti ci spiace</p>
                @enderror

                <div id="tag-output"></div>
                @error('tag')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">il post deve contenere tag</p>
                @enderror
                <input  id='tag-input' class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" placeholder="Tags"/>
                <input  id='tag-value'   style="display: none" name="tags" placeholder="Tags"/>


                <button class="flex-shrink-0 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-500 border-red-500 hover:border-red-500 text-sm border-4 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded" >
                    Condividi
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    @forelse($channel->posts as $post)
    <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
        <div id="{{$comment->id}}" class="comment-container">
        <p>{{$comment->body}}</p>
        <button id="reply-button-{{$comment->id}}">reply</button>
        <form id='reply-form-{{$comment->id}}' action="/{{$channel->id}}/reply/{{$comment->id}}" method="POST" class="invisible">
            @csrf
            <input  class=" appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" name="body" placeholder="commenta"/>
            @error('body')
            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">la risposta deve avere un testo</p>
            @enderror
        </form>
        </div>
    @endforeach
        <form action="/{{$channel->id}}/comment/{{$post->id}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input  class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" name="body" placeholder="commenta"/>
            <button class="flex-shrink-0 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-500 border-red-500 hover:border-red-500 text-sm border-4 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded" >
                Commenta
            </button>
            @error('body')
            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">il commento deve avere un testo</p>

            @enderror
        </form>
    @empty
    <p>No posts yet</p>
    @endforelse


@endsection
```

Including all my scripts in the main layout wouldn't work because they will be visible also to other pages that don't have the elements of the general page

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS is handled differently. It is not yielded but stacked.

Change

```
@yield('page-scripts')
```

to

```
@stack('page-scripts')
```

and use

```
@push('page-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/page.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

In your views. See more at: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#stacks